# CR is showing default value 6 when it should be showing 0

Tags: crystal-reports

In my CR. I have quite a few subreports. For all my subreports, I have created and inserted group name in ReportHeaderSection2 (Report Header b). In the same Report Header Section I have summarized using Count. Then again in the ReportFooterSection1 (Report Footer a) to show grand total. With other tables related, I have created 6 records showing various data.

For example, I have a table named Employeees.MainDetails.EOAsianOrAsianBritish as selected and inserted the group name in ReportHeaderSection2 (Report Header b).

Now when nothing is selected (for exampe from a combox in front end application, built in C#) in the CR data is showing something like this (as an example ethnicity data)...

```
Asian or Asian British < this is just a header title
                 6
Total            6
```

I would like the CR to show as...

```
Asian or Asian British 
                 0
Total            0
```

In the Reports Options I have checked both Convert Database NULL Values to Default and Convert Other NULL Values to Default. This did not work. I have also tried The following...

I right clicked, For both Count of Employeees.MainDetails.EOAsianOrAsianBritish in the ReportHeaderSection2 (Report Header b) and  ReportFooterSection1 (Report Footer a), Format Object > Format Editor menu appears > Select Number tab > click on Customize > Checked Suppress if Zero and Show zero value as 0. This did not work either?

**EDITED FYI**

I am using CR in Visual Studio 2010. Crystal Report Viewer.

I would be grateful if anyone can help me here.

**HUGE THANKS**

**Update 1**

I right clicked the summarized Count (CountofEOAsianOrAsianBritish) then selected the Select Expert > Record > Selected is equal to and enter the following formual....

{Employeees.MainDetails.EOAsianOrAsianBritish } = "0". This has elimated the 6 but If I try to enter some text value in front end, no value is showing the CR? So am looking into it.

**Update 2**

In my Comboox I have list of collections that I have entered. I have intentionally included a blank at the beginning then listed the collections. CR maybe picking this up. I would like a formula so CR does not count the blanks unless I am doing something wrong in summarized Count,  CountofEOAsianOrAsianBritish

**Update 3**

I tried Nick solution and I am getting ) is missing, is the DLL is missing in Visual Studio 2010.

**Update 4**

If I do... (not Isnull({Employeees.MainDetails.EOAsianOrAsianBritish})) then CR is showing output the following

```
Asian or Asian British
                    2
Bangladeshi         1
Indian              1
Pakistani           2
Total:              6
```

This is incorrect, the correct output should show....

```
Asian or Asian British
Bangladeshi         1
Indian              1
Pakistani           2
Total:              4
```

So What this is telling me is that CR is counting blank fields from the comboox. So I am wondering if anything can be done in CR? Also trim is required so when there is blank the rows are not showing blank rows.

**Update 5**

I  have tried...

```
if isnull({Employeees.MainDetails.EOAsianOrAsianBritish}) then
0 else ({Employeees.MainDetails.EOAsianOrAsianBritish})
```

This gave me the following error

> "A number is required here"

highlighting the Employeees.MainDetails.EOAsianOrAsianBritish in the 
  else statement? In the else statement shouldn't a formula count the ethnicity then show grand total in the footer?

**Nick**

The output I am getting is

```
Asian or Asian British
                    2     
Total:              2
```

When it should be showing...

```
Asian or Asian British
Indian              1
Pakistani           3
Total:              4
```

Comment: so the problem is NULLs are being added to your CountofEOAsianOrAsianBritish? and you want to know how to not count them?

Comment: What type is {Employeees.MainDetails.EOAsianOrAsianBritish}

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you're doing here, before I answer: Is what "it should be showing" one of your sub-reports or a group with a sub-report inside? Additionally, are you trying to group on {Employeees.MainDetails.EOAsianOrAsianBritish} which in Access is a boolean but when it's passed to Crystal it is a string, but what you're wanting is that when it's true those itemized counts are shown? Are "Asian or Asian British" and e.g. "Indian" two different groups? Is that how you're getting the 1 count out to the right? Grouping on a field for Indian?

Comment: If all the above is true, my thinking is that you can group on the boolean, set to be specified group order, and since we only care about it when it's "1" then we say "Asian or Asian British" as the grouping then say when EOAsianOrAsianBritish equals 1, and then on the "Others" tab say, "Discard Others". This will then have a group in your sub-report with just the data you want. Then we Group on the  type e.g. "Indian" suppress details and put the aggregate count in there with the group2 name and have an aggregate count in group 1. If you give me field names for everything, I can write this up

Comment: And if you need to pass this value of 6 to the main report, I can show you how to do that, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your formula:

```
If(Isnull({Employeees.MainDetails.EOAsianOrAsianBritish})  or ({Employeees.MainDetails.EOAsianOrAsianBritish}) = "") then (
     false
)else(
   true
);
```

Comment: I am getting error of ) is missing. Could it be DLL is missing? I am saying this based on googling. I am searching further.

Comment: I think I fixed it. There was a ) missing at the end

Comment: I should have updated more carefully but I have tried your update and I am getting the same error?

Comment: post the whole if statement

Comment: I have put everything in the thread. I can assume I am missing something in my formula, from reading your comment

Comment: It is saying A number is required here. Highlighting the (
    {Employeees.MainDetails.EOAsianOrAsianBritish}
); in the else statement

Comment: Is there alpha data in the EOAsianOrAsianBritish?  If so, and Crystal is expecting it to be a number, that might cause that.

Comment: @Andrew - I don't know what you mean? The count is counting from the combox which user selects when they create a record, as my updates

Comment: what is the datatype in your table for EOAsianOrAsianBritish?

Comment: You can also try If Isnull({Employeees.MainDetails.EOAsianOrAsianBritish}) or ({Employeees.MainDetails.EOAsianOrAsianBritish}) = "" then (
     0
)else(
    ToNumber({Employeees.MainDetails.EOAsianOrAsianBritish})
);

Comment: @Nick - datatype is Text from MS Access. I have been asked to developed the application this way and believe me this the only time I will ever do it

Comment: @Andrew - I am receiving error of "The result of selection formula must be Boolean"

Comment: @Nick - I believe in you. Give is a moment

Comment: @Nick- Looks like the report is showing correctly. So I would like "say" thank you for your valuable time and effect.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution Description

This is a solution for creating a report with a sub-report and sub-report groupings with aggregate values that are then passed to the main report.

### Solution Assumptions

- This solution assumes that you are using at least Crystal Reports 2008 if not newer.
- This solution assumes that you know how to connect your data source properly in both the main report and the sub-report.
- This solution assumes that you have valid data and your purpose is to group data into two different levels in a sub-report, without detail information, and pass the result to the main report.

### Solution Instruction Order

1. Create sub-report
2. Create specified group
3. Create type group
4. Suppress details
5. Add summary/aggregate field
6. Suppress unneeded group headers/footers
7. Create variable to be passed to main report

## Solution

Prerequisites: have Crystal Reports designer open to your report and have data source connected, logged on, and verified.

### Create Sub-Report

1. Using the sub-report insertion tool, name your sub-report and click on Report Wizard
2. Add your data source and click Finish
3. Place sub-report in appropriate place on main report and set its width
4. (Optional) Right-click and choose Format Sub-Report and go to Border tab to remove borders
5. Double click the sub-report to open the designer
6. Remove all the fields that Crystal adds
7. Delete the extra sections on Report the header and footer

You now have a blank sub-report ready to go and next we will start our groupings.

### Create Specified Group

We are creating a specified group in the sub-report to limit the amount of data so that we do not have blank lines.

1. Go to Group Expert
2. Select the field that will filter your data and add it as a group (e.g. Employeees.MainDetails.EOAsianOrAsianBritish)
3. Click the Options button
4. Select "specified group order" from the drop down for group sorting
5. Click the Specified Group tab
6. Click "New" and enter the heading for this group (e.g. "Asian or Asian British")
7. Select a comparison operator (e.g. "is equal to") and give it the value you want to filter for (e.g. 1) click "OK"
   Note: You can add additional specified groups OR add more to this specified group by clicking the new tab within the group name screen to add an "or" section.
8. Back to the Group Screen, go to the "Others" tab
9. Select "Discard all others"
   Note: This is only discarding records for this sub-report not the main-one.
10. Click "OK"

Your specified group which will filter only the values you want in your subreport should now be created and your header should be added to the group header.

### Create Type Group

1. Go back to Group Expert
2. Add another group based on another field that you want to count (e.g. ethnicity)
3. (Optional) Go to "Options" and click the "Options" tab to give your groups a different name based on the field value if your data source is not providing them
   Note: I can show you how to do this, if need be, but for now, I am assuming things like "Indian" are already there as a grouping option.
4. Click "OK" and you should now have a second group with a group heading
5. (Optional) Un-bold the second group heading and move it to the right slightly to give an indent under the above header group
6. Suppress this group's footer as it won't be needed

You should now have two groups, one with your main group header and a second with your summary group header. Now, we need to suppress the details.

### Suppress Details

This is IMPORTANT otherwise you will get a bunch of unwanted lines of data. Right-click the Detail section row header and select "Suppress." Also, suppress the report header and footer as we will not need them.

### Add Summary/Aggregate Field

Now, we are going to create our summary field that, for example, does our counting.

1. Click on the "Add Summary" button
2. Select the field you want to summarize (e.g. Employee Number or something that distinguishes each detail line)
3. Select the summary type (e.g. Count)
4. Either select the group you want to add the summary to or (as I recommend) check "add to to all group levels"
5. Click "OK" and summary fields should be added to each group level's footer
   Note: This may unsuppress some rows, but you can re-do that.
6. Move the second grouping's summary from the footer to the header and place where you want it to show
7. Add a text field to the main group's footer that says "Total" and place appropriately
8. (Optional) Move the top grouping's summary in its footer to line up with the summary in the secondary group's header
9. Delete the summary in the report footer
10. Re-suppress report footer and secondary group footer

Technically, your sub-report is done. If you preview just the sub-report itself, it should show correct aggregate data.

### Create Variable to be Passed to Main Report

This is optional, but a lot of times, you want to pass this value to the main report.

1. Create a new formula field, name it whatever you want but a relevant name to its meaning is helpful
2. The formula should be `Shared NumberVar TotalCount := Sum({EmployeeNum}, {EOAsianOrAsianBritish})`
   Note: What this does is create a shared NumberVar that you can then use later in the main report. To make things easier on yourself, instead of typing everything out after the `:=` you can just scroll the Summary Field (e.g. Count on Main Group) in the Report Fields and double click it to add it to the formula.
3. Click Save
4. Add the field to your suppressed report footer

Now, you have a total you can pass to the main report. Some things to note: this entire sub-report CAN be suppressed within itself and still have the number be passed to the main. However, if it's suppressed in the main report, the number won't pass. Finally, the formula for the formula field in the main report is `Shared NumberVar TotalCount` and that will give you a number that you can work with.

## Conclusion

Yes, I am aware there are record selection techniques that could also be used to accomplish the limiting of data in the sub-report. However, this method allows you to have one or more groups not just a report header and footer for the sub-report if need be.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask. I know this was a lot of information to throw at you.

Comment: thank you for this and I will definitely try this but pls bear with me. It may take a day or two for me to reply. I am interested the Create Variable to be Passed to Main Report you have advised.